# How do you use the term "of which"?

Tags: word-usage

I'm trying to find how you would use the term *of which* in a sentence.

Comment: https://linguaholic.com/linguablog/how-to-use-of-which-in-a-sentence/

Answer (score 0):

> **PEU  p.476, second  edition****            ***of which; that...of***
> Instead of *whose*, we can use *of...that*  or *that...of* (less formal)  to refer to things, and  these are sometimes preferred. The most  common  word order is **noun + of which** or **that...of**, but **of  which + noun** is also possible.
> Compare the following four ways  of expressing  the same idea.
>
> - *He's written a book **whose name** I've forgotten.*
> - *He's written a book **the name of which** I've forgotten.*
> - *He's written a book **that** I've forgotten **the name of**.*
> - *He's written a book **of which** I've forgotten **the name**.*

** *Practical English Usage*